# Highcharts Y Axis overlay while re-rendering with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, spline

I've put together a sample for my case, using `spline` chart with `scrollablePlotArea` option defined. When page finished loading the first time, the Y Axis is correctly rendered, but due to some re-rendering from the parent component, the Y Axis will be overlapped by the plot area.

Inspecting this behavior, I've figured out that the first time the page load, the Y values are rendered in `highcharts-fixed` div, but any event makes this chart re-render, the Y Values will be rendered in `highcharts-scrolling`, I think this is the root cause for this issue.

Sample link: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-wm6g6

Any ideas for the workaround for this would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi @Duc Hong, If you have a static chart, the simplest solution is to set `allowChartUpdate` option to `false`: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#options-details

Comment: well, I've managed to resolve this with option `immutable` set to `true` while initing the component, as the doc said. But still opening to the root cause of this, since in my case, the data will be updated after I've selected an option from a dropdown

Comment: You have used old version of the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper. Please use the latest one (2.2.2): https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-i4xgz

Comment: oh sorry for the old version on the demo links, but in my real project I'm using 2.2.2 too.  Funny thing is when I copied the options on your link, though it works on codesandbox but the overlay issue stills happens on my local, so weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem is a Highcharts bug, reprted here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8862

**Reproduced issue:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/96v4q8nk/

As a workaround you can use the code from the github thread, but also setting `immutable` to `true` or `allowChartUpdate` to `false` should resolve the issue.

```
<HighchartsReact
    ...
    immutable = { true }
/>
```

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#options-details

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look and try to reapply his workaround in my project